What are the assumptions of beta-binomial models, and how do I test for them in r?
I want to model the effects of dispersal distance (disp) and reproductive rate (rep) on colonization rate, quantified as the number recolonized habitat cells (colonized_hab) divided by the number of available habitat cells (vacant_hab), which is a proportion derived from counts (i.e., the count of habitat cells recolonized in a given simulated landscape relative to the count of habitat cells available to be recolonized). Both my predictor variables are continuous ('rep' ranges from 0.05 to 1 in increments of 0.1, and 'disp' ranges from 5 10 105  in increments of 20). I initially ran a generalized linear model with a binomial distribution using the glm() function in R:
glm(cbind(colonized_hab, vacant_hab - colonized_hab) ~ rep + disp, 
          family="binomial", data=dat)

But the output indicated that the model was overdispersed:
Residual deviance: 174938 on 1197 degrees of freedom

To deal with overdispersion in the model I ran a beta-binomial model, using glmmTMB function (without any random effects):
mod2 <- glmmTMB(cbind(colonized_hab, vacant_hab - colonized_hab) ~ 
         rep + disp, family="betabinomial", data=dat)

Now that I have run this model, I want to know what the assumptions are, and what kind of diagnostic tests I should be conducting to determine whether the model assumptions have been met.
So far I've tried using the DHARMa package to run some diagnostic tests:
res <- simulateResiduals(mod2, plot = TRUE)


hist(simulateResiduals(mod2))


testZeroInflation(mod2)


However, I'm not quite sure of what I should be looking for in terms of the assumptions of beta-binomial models. Any thoughts or insights would be much appreciated. And if my data do not meet the assumptions, what are suggested next steps in dealing with overdispersion? Any feedback or insights are much appreciated.
For context, here is a screenshot of my data.frame, showing the structure of my dataset (note that this is only a small subset of the dataset -  the full dataset has 1200 rows, with each row being an observation):

Vacant_hab is the count of available habitat patches and colonized_hab is the count of the vacant habitat patches that have been recolonized. Using the first row as an example, the proportion of vacant habitat that has been recolonized (i.e., the colonization rate) is 754/1296 = 0.52.

Note that the screenshot of my dataframe is just a small portion of my data - in total there are 1200 rows with dispersal distance ranging from 5-100 and reproductive rate ranging from 0.05 to 1.

Your outcome is measured as a value between zero and one, correct?

Yes, that's correct. There are a some 0s and 1s but it's mostly a proportion in between the two.

Thanks for the clarification. What about that seems to be beta-binomial-distributed?

Based on what I’ve read it seems that beta-binomial models are often used to deal with overdispersed count-based proportion data, which is what I have. Are you suggesting a different approach?

Why do you describe the outcome as a value between 0 and 1? What do vacant_hab and colonized_hab measure? What does it mean to observe (vacant_hab, colonized_hab) = (1296, 754). Also the model shown is binomial, not beta-binomial. You need to change the family to family = betabinomial(link = "logit") for a beta-binomial model.

@dipetkov the “binomial” in the second model was a copy and paste error, the actual model was run with “betabinomial.” I will edit my original question to correct that. Vacant_hab is the count of available habitat patches and colonized_hab is the count of the vacant habitat patches that have been recolonized. So in the example above the proportion of vacant habitat that has been recolonized is 754/1296 = 0.52.

Thanks for the clarification. Just making sure: And all the diagnostic plots (which indicate some issues with how well the model fits the data) are for mod2? Can you say more about the predictors as well, disp and rep? Are they both continuous? If yes, one option to explore to improve the model is to relax the linearity assumption, for example by introducing splines.

@dipetkov that's correct, the diagnostic plots are for mod2. Both reproductive rate (rep) and dispersal distance (disp) are continuous variables.

Good. The first DHARMa plot is quite informative. If I read it correctly, the model underpredicts colonization rates in the mid-range. You can try adding splines and/or an interaction between disp and rep. I just noticed the phrase "in a given timestep" which suggest that you may have multiple observations of the same patch, and if that's the case then the model needs to account for a time dimension as well. In any case, it may help to edit the question with all the relevant background information.

Didn't find a great CV thread about glmmTMB with the betabinomial family; perhaps this draft textbook chapter will help: A mixed model with a betabinomial error from Data Analysis and Graphics Using R, available here.

@dipetkov thanks, I'll have a look at this resource.
